# memcached max 100820 items per slab limit?

Tags: memory, memcached

We store a lot of small fixed length values in memcached, and I constantly observe how memcached used memory stops growing not reaching its defined memory limit. Usually it stops growing upon reaching 100820 items in the smallest slab. I tried playing with -f factor to no avail: growth stops upon reaching 100820 items in one slab.

Is there anyway to amend the 100820 items limit? I can't find info in regards to it anywhere.

Detailed statistics is below.

Run string:

```
/usr/bin/memcached -m 328 -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1 -n 52 -C
```

3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

memcached 1.4.13

```
STAT 1:chunk_size 104
STAT 1:chunks_per_page 10082
STAT 1:total_pages 10
STAT 1:total_chunks 100820
STAT 1:used_chunks 100820
STAT 1:free_chunks 0
STAT 1:free_chunks_end 0
STAT 1:mem_requested 10407999
STAT 1:get_hits 262079
STAT 1:cmd_set 321590
STAT 1:delete_hits 0
STAT 1:incr_hits 0
STAT 1:decr_hits 0
STAT 1:cas_hits 0
STAT 1:cas_badval 0
STAT 1:touch_hits 0

stats sizes
STAT 96 8
STAT 128 100812
STAT 160 5
STAT 192 195
STAT 224 4533
STAT 256 7859
STAT 288 10608
STAT 320 21084
STAT 352 26051
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

On the man page, you'll see an option for -I  which allows you to adjust the size of your slab (http://linux.die.net/man/1/memcached), which if you use in conjunction with the -f Factor switch, you'll soon realize how to maximize memcache storage sizes.

And if not, there is a much better explanation here: http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/a-few-memcache-gotchas